# How to connect Mongolab from the shell behind a proxy?

Tags: mongodb, shell, heroku, amazon-s3, proxy

I am trying to connect Mongolab URI from my mongo shell and its showing

```
    MongoDB shell version: 3.1.7
    connecting to: ds015859.mlab.com:15859/instabuy
    2016-03-16T16:49:15.581+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1]
    Failed to connect to 54.224.218.3:15859, reason: errno:10061
    No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused   
    2016-03-16T16:49:15.581+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't   connect to server ds015859.mlab.com:15859, connection attempt failed :
    connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:216:14
```

I am behind a http web proxy in my college, but I already set my HTTP_PROXY variable. I already connected to heroku by setting the proxy variable also. But other services like Mongolab, Mailchimp and AWS s3 are refusing connection..what should I do, Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Different services such as MongoDb and others use custom command protocols to communicate with clients. For, example, in MongoDb they use binary [MongoDB Wire Protocol](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-wire-protocol/). A HTTP proxy can handle only a limited set of protocols, most proxies are configured to proxy the HTTP text protocol only. So, you can't connect to mongo server via such proxy unless you have a HTTP-wrapper around the mongo protocol.

If you want to connect remotely to any service with any protocol indirectly via something like a proxy then you have to use tunneling. Tunnels can work at the IP:port level (SSH tunnels, as an example) or be established over VPN (OpenVPN tunnels, for example). In both cases you first establish a tunnel with your "proxy" server and then redirect mongo connection to that tunnel.